# How to add property to nested json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a nested array of object. example:

```
var data = [
  {
    propertyName: propertyValue,
    childs : [
      {
         propertyName: propertyValue,
         childs : [
           {
            propertyName: propertyValue,
            childs : [
             {
               propertyName: propertyValue,   
               childs : []
             }
            ]
           }
         ]
      },

      {
         propertyName: propertyValue,
         childs : [
           {
            propertyName: propertyValue,
            childs : []
           }
         ]
      }

.......

    ]

  }
]
```

How can I add some property in every `childs` if found? If 'id' and 'parentId' need to add then also fine. Any clue?

```
var data = [
  {
    propertyName: propertyValue,
    childs : [
      {
         propertyName: propertyValue,
         anotherPrperty: value
         childs : [
           {
            propertyName: propertyValue,
            anotherPrperty: value
            childs : [
             {
               propertyName: propertyValue,
               anotherPrperty: value   
               childs : []
             }
            ]
           }
         ]
      },

      {
         propertyName: propertyValue,
         childs : [
           {
            propertyName: propertyValue,
            anotherPrperty: value
            childs : []
           }
         ]
      }

.......

    ]

  }
]
```

Comment: Hello, what have you tried? Hint: you need a recursive approach over the _children_ nodes ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that add the property to all items in an array and then pass the child arrays to the same function recursively:

```js
var data = [{propertyName: 'propertyValue',childs : [{propertyName: 'propertyValue',childs : [{propertyName: 'propertyValue',childs : [{propertyName: 'propertyValue',   childs : []}]}]},{propertyName: 'propertyValue',childs : [{propertyName: 'propertyValue',childs : []}]}  ] }]

function addProp(arr, name, value){
    arr.forEach(item => {
        item[name] = value                // add property
        addProp(item.childs, name, value) // pass children back to function
    })
}

addProp(data, "testProp", "testValue")
console.log(data)
```

If you don't want to add the prop to the first level, you can just call `forEach()` on the array and start with the children. Something like:

```
data.forEach(item => addProp(item.childs, "testProp", "testValue"))
```